# Получение данных из Яндекс Метрики с использованием userParams

Tags: node.js, yandex-metrika-api, яндекс-метрика

В яндекс Метрику передаются параметры пользователя `userParams`:

```
{
  "partner_name": "Тестовый партнер",
  "partner_guid": "551d7b62-8892-12d9-aa79-605054503031",
  "user_id": "1",
  "user_roles": [
    "Менеджер",
    "Логист",
    "Бухгалтер"
  ]
}
```

Задача - использовать эти параметры (`userParams`) для группировки и фильтрации при построении своих отчетов.

Данные собираются, проверено. Теперь вопрос: как можно отфильтровать/получить/сгруппировать такие данные через API метрики? Например, получить общее количество визитов Тестового партнера (`partner_name` или `partner_guid`). Или получить "сырые" данные, где будет проставлен сохраненный в недрах Метрики `userParams` для самостоятельной обработки.

Может быть, такого и нельзя сделать. Нашел список параметров в [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/metrika/doc/api2/api_v1/attrandmetr/dim_all-docpage/), и среди них нет этого, хотя есть `ym:s:paramsLevel1`, но я не уверен что это именно то.

Для отладки я использую такой скрипт, посмотрите мои попытки в `filters:`:

```js
"use strict";

const
  querystring = require('querystring'),
  https = require('https')
  ;

let params = {
  access_token: "****************", // мой токен
  counter: "0000000" // номер счетчика
}

let analyticsParams = {
  "ids": `${params.counter}`,
  // filters: "EXISTS(ym:s:paramsLevel1=='userParams')", // возвращает ноль
  // filters: "EXISTS(ym:s:paramsLevel1=='partner_guid')",  // возвращает ноль
  // filters: "EXISTS(ym:s:paramsLevel1=='partner_guid' AND ym:s:paramsLevel2=='551d7b62-8892-12d9-aa79-605054503031')",  // возвращает ноль
  // filters: "EXISTS(ym:pv:URL=='login')", // возвращает ноль, почему?
  filters: "ym:s:trafficSource=='organic'", // работает
  "metrics": [
    "ym:s:visits"
  ],
  dimensions: [ "ym:s:browser" ]
};


let getOptions = {
  host: 'api-metrika.yandex.net',
  port: '443',
  path: '/stat/v1/data/?' + querystring.stringify(analyticsParams),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-yametrika+json",
    "Authorization": `OAuth ${params.access_token}`
  }
}

console.log(getOptions);


function getData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {

    https.get(getOptions, (resp) => {
      let data = '';

      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      resp.on('end', () => {
        data = JSON.parse(data);

        if(data.error) {
          console.log("Error", data.error);
          reject(new Error(data.error));
          return;
        }

        resolve(data);
      });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
      reject(new Error('Произошла ошибка: ' + err.message));
    });

  });
}

let run = async () => {
  try {
    let data = await getData();
    console.log("----------- resilts -----------");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log();
    console.log(data.data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Техподдержка сообщила, что по параметру `userParams` нельзя ни фильтровать, ни получать данные.